# Reverse current in diodes

Tags: pn-junction, reverse-bias

I'm getting started with electronics and couldn't help but wonder about this:

When the PN junction diode is reverse biased (P connected to the negative terminal and N connected to the positive terminal) shouldn't there be a large reverse current as the electrons (which are essentially the equivalent of minority charge carriers in the P region) get injected into the P region through the conductor?

The depletion region can't really hinder the movement of electrons from P to N region as the field itself is from N region to the P region. Considering the very high concentration of free electrons in a conductor, shouldn't there be a huge reverse current?

Comment: You appear to be saying that diodes shouldn't work.

Comment: In general, metals do not inject electrons into P regions of a semiconductor.

Comment: As Andy implies, if it happens, it must be true. Try this on the physics site, they get into Fermi levels and suchlike there.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy if so, then what exactly happens at the metal-semiconductor junction on both the ends of the diode ?

Comment: @SanthoshS this is not a chat forum... if you have an additional question, then edit your post

Comment: Do you have a particular reason for thinking that the electrons would be able to travel through the P-type silicon? It's kind of the point of P-type silicon that electrons (in the conduction band) don't move through it easily.

Comment: The concept you're missing is "ohmic contact".

Comment: @TannerSwett Actually, an NPN transistor works because electrons move freely through P-type Si. The difference in a diode is that the ohmic contact to the P-type doesn't inject electrons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carrier diffusion takes place whenever there is a gradient in the density of a free electrons and/or holes. Such a gradient exists at the boundary between a metal and a semiconductor. There are, in general, more free electrons in the metal than in the semiconductor, and so free electrons diffuse from the metal into the semiconductor even if the semiconductor is P-type.

When free electrons diffuse from a metal into P-type semiconductor, they generally do not last long as free electrons. Unless the P-type material is very weakly doped, there are many holes present. Holes and electrons randomly recombine. The number of excess free electrons (i.e the number greater than the equilibrium electron concentration) falls off more or less exponentially. The diffusion length of electrons in a P-type semiconductor is a measure of how far into the P-type material excess free electrons are, on average, likely to penetrate.

If a diode is "long enough", the density of free electrons in the P-material some distance from the metal contact is virtually independent of the density at the metal-semiconductor junction. The density of free electrons in this regime, \$n_0\$ is

$$n_0 = \frac{n_i^2}{N_A}$$

where \$n_i\$ is the intrinsic carrier concentration, and \$N_A\$ is the concentration of acceptor dopants.

As the intrinsic carrier concentration is temperature dependent, the density of free electrons will also be temperature dependent.

Contrary to a common (incorrect) belief, the depletion region of a PN junction does not hinder the flow of excess minority carriers across it. Excess minority carriers are easily "swept" across the depletion region of a PN junction by the electric field that is present. Thus, the rate of such minority carriers crossing the PN junction depends primarily upon the concentration of minority carriers at the boundary of the depletion region. An analogy that I use in my mind for the free electrons at the edge of the depletion region is that of a pool of water at the top of a high waterfall. The rate of the flow over the waterfall does not depend upon the drop in the waterfall, but on the rate at which water reaches the edge.

Because the flow of minority carriers is restricted by the concentration near the PN junction, the flow of electrons from the metal into the P-region is likewise restricted. Under equilibrium conditions, the flows are the same. If the (net) flow of electrons across the metal-P-type-semiconductor junction (temporarily) exceeds the flow across the PN junction, then the concentration of electrons in the P region will increase, creating an electric field which will oppose the flow across the metal-P-type-semiconductor junction.

If a PN diode is reverse biased, net current will indeed flow from the metal into the P region, across the P region, across the PN junction, through the N region and into the N-side metal contact. Because this current is restricted by the density of free electrons on the P side of the depletion region, and this density, in diodes with sufficiently long P regions depends on intrinsic carrier concentration, the maximum current through the reverse biased diode (i.e. the reverse saturation current) is independent of the applied reverse voltage, but strongly dependent upon the temperature.

Free electrons, can of course also diffuse across the metal-N-type-semiconductor junction. However, the concentration of free electrons in N-type semiconductors is much higher than in P-type. Diffusion of electrons *into* the N-type semiconductor is not a major factor in the current of a reverse biased diode. However, the flow of electrons from the N-type semiconductor into the metal is a major component of the current there.

This brings me to something that is not entirely clear to me. It may be related to how some metal semiconductor junctions are Ohmic, and some form Schottky junctions, another topic that is not entirely clear to me.

By symmetry with the P-side dynamics, one might suppose that in a reverse biased diode, holes form at the metal-N-type-semiconductor junction. However, I suspect (but do not know) that is rarely the case. The free electrons in the metal are in the conduction band, but the electrons that leave an atom to form a hole are in the valence band. My guess is that this is not an energetically favorable process for electrons to leave the valence band of the semiconductor to enter the conduction band of the metal. However, to counter my leaning, is the fact that Schottky have a reputation for high reverse leakage current. That latter fact may be totally unrelated however. In any event, holes created at the metal semiconductor junction will readily recombine with electrons in the N region, and so the concentration of holes at the N-side edge of the depletion region would be primarily determined by the intrinsic carrier concentration, rather than by such hole creation. Perhaps someone with more knowledge can shed some light on the question of whether there is hole creation at the metal-N-type-semiconductor junction of a reverse biased diode, in analogy with the electrons that diffuse into the semiconductor on the P-side.

Comment: This solves my question partly. What happens on the N side. Electrons are the majority carriers on the N side and should be "pushed away" away from the junction/depletion region and are free to move out the N side into the conductor. Since we measure current with an ammeter connected in series with the diode, shouldn't there be a surge in the current at least for a brief moment? If so shouldn't the transient graph have a little peak and then go down to the normal reverse current level(micro ampere level of current)?

Comment: @SanthoshS I did a major rewrite that will hopefully provide clarity with respect to disagreements with another answer. I also attempted to address the issue of the N side process. Unfortunately, I, myself am not entirely clear. Electrons in the conduction band of a semiconductor are similar to electrons in the conduction band of a metal. I understand diffusion between the two. However, metals don't have "holes" that I know of, so I think what happens on the N side may not be analogous to what happens on P side. My edit addresses this, but somewhat speculatively.

Comment: In response to "metals don't have 'holes" that I know of," here is my understanding of how conduction works in semiconductors and metals. A semiconductor has two relevant bands that charge carriers can move around in. The first is the valence band, which is usually nearly full of electrons. A "missing" electron here is usually called a "hole," and it behaves as a charge carrier. The second is the conduction band, which is usually nearly empty of electrons. An electron here is usually just called... well... an "electron," and it behaves as a charge carrier. (cont'd...)

Comment: A metal, on the other hand, only has one relevant band that charge carriers can move around in. That band is usually roughly half full of electrons (I have no idea what the actual number usually is). Here, as far as I know, it's equally valid to consider either the electrons or the holes as the charge carriers; a hole here is no different from the absence of an electron, and an electron here is no different from the absence of a hole. I don't know whether or not there's an important difference between the way that electrons cross a metal–semiconductor junction, and the way that holes do.

Comment: @TannerSwett electrons in a valence band are (at least for the time being) part of a covalent *bond*. A missing electron missing from this lattice of bonds is a hole. I don't see anything comparable in a metal, as metals don't have covalent bonds. My difficulty is in imagining an electron leaving a covalent bond in the semiconductor, to join the metal's conduction band, or at least imagining that it happens frequently. An electron can leave one covalent bond to complete another because the two states have similar energy, and not merely because there is "room" for the electron.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy i previously found a similar explanation using the Schottky barrier formation. What puzzles me is that the so formed Schottky barrier(between the N region and the metal contacts)which will be reverse biased when the diode is reverse biased should breakdown pretty quickly since the Schottky barrier won't be much stronger than the PN diodes barrier, so the transient graph must look very different.